# Visiting sites previously never visited results in page not found or junk CSS

Tags: windows-8, router, internet, dns, firmware

I have recently inherited a workstation which I installed a brand new SSD in and then installed Windows 8 (I previously have not bothered with it).  Bypassing Internet Explorer, I immediately installed Chrome and retrieved all of my settings and extensions and what-not.

When visiting a site which I have not yet visited on this computer, I am first met with "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.tomshardware.com".  After a refresh I get the page I am trying to load, but it has no CSS applied, and so the page is nigh on un-usable.  A further refresh yields the page properly formatted.  What gives?  Anyone else encountered this behavior?

I have reset the profile in Chrome and cleared caches and remove/created firewall rules, and so far nothing has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a hacked router.  Party unknown used an exploit where they could request a password change on my router without authenticating themselves.  Then they changed the DNS server values on the router.  This interrupted most of my browsing traffic and eventually started directing me to nefarious Windows Update and Shockwave Update pages urging me to update those softwares.

## Caution

Anyone seeing the above symptoms, try logging into your router.  If you cannot and you absolutely know that your password is correct, you have been DNS-jacked.  You will need to perform a factory reset on the router, and I would urge you to update the firmware ASAP.  In my case the exploit was identifed several versions back, but looking through the changelog I did not see where NetGear had fixed it.  So, NetGear firmware out, DD-WRT in.  I can be reasonably assured that the people writing that firmware will fix dangerous bugs like the one above.